# separatorInset is not working Xcode 6?

Tags: objective-c, xcode6

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell  *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];



cell.textLabel.text = [self.arrayOfPlaces objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

return cell;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 8 onwards you need to set `layoutMargins` to adjust the cell separators.

```
[cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

Since this property is not available in iOS 7 and below, you need to check before assigning. You can either use `respondsToSelector`.

```
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

OR in your custom cell class just add this below

```
-(UIEdgeInsets)layoutMargins
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

You need to retain `cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;` to make it compatible with iOS 7.